# FN+F2 opens "Power Statistics". How to make it run a command?

Tags: shortcut-keys, function-keys

I am using ubuntu 15.04 with `unity`. <kbd>Fn</kbd>  keys are working and I am getting results while running acpi_listen and pressing a combination of <kbd>Fn</kbd>  <kbd>Fx</kbd>  key.

Now I want to make a keyboard shortcut to control the screen's brightness. I have already installed `xbacklight` and it's working when I use it as a terminal command  `xbacklight -10%`. I can also go to keyboard's settings and add a custom shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd>  and it actually works when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the `left arrow`.

The problem is that when I am pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd>  combination, it is registered as `Battery` in shortcut settings, and when pressing the comb, it opens the `Power Statistics` window.

Is there any way to change that? I haven't found anything searching that on the net. I have found only solutions for not working <kbd>Fn</kbd>  keys and other outdated information.

Any help is appreciated.

Image for clarification:

[image: shortcut window]

BTW, linux noob and not native speaker here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by going to "keyboard" (settings -> keyboard, or just type keyboard into the search bar). Then, click the arrow next to "system", and choose "hardware". Click "show power statistics", double click the keyboard binding and press backspace (this will clear the shortcut). You should be good to go after that!